# mysql join 2 tables - but have to join same table twice

Tags: mysql, join

I am making a Softball Schedule for my league.  I have a TEAMS table and a GAMES table.  TEAMS is id & team_name.  GAMES table has date, time, home_team(relates to TEAMS table id) and away_team(relates to TEAMS table id).

I want to select all of the games from the GAMES table, but instead of home_team and away_team display the id of the team, i want it to display the team_name from the TEAMS table.

Here is my query, but there are problems...

```
SELECT games.date, games.time, games.home_team, 
games.away_team, teams.team_name FROM games JOIN teams ON games.home_team=teams.id 
JOIN teams on games.away_team=teams.team;
```

> ## 1066 - Not unique table/alias: teams

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cause you will have to supply different table alias since you are joining the same table twice like

```
SELECT games.date, games.time,
t.team_name as home_team,
t1.team_name as away_team 
FROM games g 
LEFT JOIN teams t ON g.home_team=t.id 
LEFT JOIN teams t1 on g.away_team=t1.team
```

Comment: Here is the results... not quite what i need, but i think i'm getting closer.. I wish i could show you a screen shot of the results, but i got all of the dates, times, home_teams (still just showing the id), away_teams (still just showing the id) then there is the team_name from the teams table, that has 1 of the teams name, which is the home_teams actual name.

Comment: here is where you can find an actual screen shot of the results. [link](http://bjwtech.com/Capture.PNG)

Comment: i actually uploaded the wrong screen shot the first time from your first query sorry.  Here is the real link to it :[link](http://bjwtech.com/Capture.PNG)... i tried your edited query and it returned 0 rows....

Comment: I made three screen snips - [teams](http://bjwtech.com/teams.PNG) - whats in my teams tables. [games](http://bjwtech.com/games.PNG) - whats in my games table and then here is an example of what i want returned (I just photoshopped it) [desired_results](http://bjwtech.com/desired.png).  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You might want to change the join to left join instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of table aliases.  So, you would have something like this:

```
SELECT games.date, games.time, games.home_team, games.away_team, teams1.team_name 
FROM games 
   JOIN teams AS teams1 ON games.home_team=teams1.id 
   JOIN teams AS teams2 ON games.away_team=teams2.team;
```

Comment: that's an entirely unrelated problem.  Your question is about reusing the same table in multiple joins, and this is how you do it.  It has nothing to do with trying to execute a query which, given the contents of your tables, is not yielding any results.

Comment: I made three screen snips - [teams](http://bjwtech.com/teams.PNG) - whats in my teams tables. [games](http://bjwtech.com/games.PNG) - whats in my games table and then here is an example of what i want returned (I just photoshopped it) [desired_results](http://bjwtech.com/desired.png).  I am new at this, and i am just trying to learn some back end so i can try to fill a vacant position at my job

Answer (score 0):

WOOHOO I GOT IT!!!!! Column aliases and table aliases were needed here!!!!!! I cant believe i did it!

SELECT g.day, g.date, g.time, t.team_name AS away_team, t2.team_name AS home_team
FROM GAMES AS g
JOIN TEAMS AS t ON away_team = t.id
JOIN TEAMS AS t2 ON home_team = t2.id